# NullPointer exception converting SOAP string message to SoapMessage

Tags: java, xml, soap, jaxp, saaj

I'm converting an XML string to a SOAPMessage.  However, I end up getting a NullPointerException when attempting to invoke the service.  When stepping through the code, I could tell it was trying to set a null prefix to this uri namespace: "urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:query:3.0".

Code:

```
    //PORT_NAME={urn:ihe:iti:xds-b:2007}RespondingGateway_Port_Soap12
    //SERVICE_NAME={urn:ihe:iti:xds-b:2007}RespondingGateway_Service
        Service service = Service.create(SERVICE_NAME);
        service.addPort(PORT_NAME, SOAPBinding.SOAP12HTTP_BINDING, endpointUrl);
        Dispatch<SOAPMessage> dispatch = service.createDispatch(PORT_NAME,
                SOAPMessage.class, Service.Mode.MESSAGE);
        squashWSA(dispatch);
        addHttpHeaders(dispatch, messageId);
        //set the request timeout value
        dispatch.getRequestContext().put(JAXWSProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT, haimsConnectTimeout);
        dispatch.getRequestContext().put(JAXWSProperties.REQUEST_TIMEOUT, haimsReceiveTimeout);

            byte[] msgBytes = domToBytes(rawSoapRqst);
    MessageFactory mf = MessageFactory.newInstance(SOAPConstants.SOAP_1_2_PROTOCOL);
            SOAPMessage request = mf.createMessage(new MimeHeaders(), new ByteArrayInputStream(msgBytes));
            SOAPMessage response = dispatch.invoke(request);
```

Stacktrace:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.impl.ElementImpl.addNamespaceDeclaration(ElementImpl.java:528)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.message.saaj.SaajStaxWriter.writeNamespace(SaajStaxWriter.java:193)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.util.xml.XMLStreamReaderToXMLStreamWriter.handleStartElement(XMLStreamReaderToXMLStreamWriter.java:215)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.util.xml.XMLStreamReaderToXMLStreamWriter.bridge(XMLStreamReaderToXMLStreamWriter.java:124)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.message.stream.StreamMessage.writePayloadTo(StreamMessage.java:381)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.message.stream.StreamMessage.writeEnvelope(StreamMessage.java:417)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.message.stream.StreamMessage.writeTo(StreamMessage.java:395)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.message.MessageWrapper.writeTo(MessageWrapper.java:230)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.message.saaj.SAAJFactory.readAsSOAPMessage(SAAJFactory.java:279)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.message.saaj.SAAJFactory.readAsSAAJ(SAAJFactory.java:206)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.message.saaj.SAAJFactory.read(SAAJFactory.java:195)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.message.AbstractMessageImpl.toSAAJ(AbstractMessageImpl.java:200)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.message.MessageWrapper.readAsSOAPMessage(MessageWrapper.java:180)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.client.dispatch.SOAPMessageDispatch.toReturnValue(SOAPMessageDispatch.java:104)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.client.dispatch.SOAPMessageDispatch.toReturnValue(SOAPMessageDispatch.java:75)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.client.dispatch.DispatchImpl.doInvoke(DispatchImpl.java:289)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.client.dispatch.DispatchImpl.invoke(DispatchImpl.java:304)
        at com.domain.wrapper.h.Queryh.queryh(Queryh.java:87)
        at com.domain.wrapper.h.QueryhTest.test(QueryhTest.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

SOAP Message:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
       <soap:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
          <wsa:To>https://service.com:8443/ABC</wsa:To>
          <wsa:Action>urn:ihe:iti:2007:CrossGatewayQuery</wsa:Action>
          <wsa:ReplyTo>
             <wsa:Address>urn:ihe:iti:2007:CrossGatewayQuery</wsa:Address>
          </wsa:ReplyTo>
          <wsa:MessageID>325b321a-5080-11e3-9c3c-6bf842da5cba</wsa:MessageID>
          <!-- These must be namespace-qualified
          <xxx-transaction-id>325d7c0b-5080-11e3-9c3c-6bf842da5cba</xxx-transaction-id>
          <xxx-fullname>Brandon L Cooper</xxx-fullname>
          <xxx-sitename>HAIMS2</xxx-sitename>
          <xxx-sitenumber>0001</xxx-sitenumber>
          <xxx-ssn>999428882</xxx-ssn>
          <xxx-purpose-of-use>Routine Medical Care</xxx-purpose-of-use>
          -->
       </soap:Header>

       <soap:Body>
          <query:AdhocQueryRequest xmlns:query="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:query:3.0" xmlns:rim="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:3.0" xmlns:urn="urn:ihe:iti:xds-b:2007" xmlns:urn2="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:query:3.0">
             <rim:AdhocQuery xmlns:urn3="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:3.0">
                <rim:Slot name="$XDSDocumentEntryPatientId">
                   <rim:ValueList>
                      <rim:Value>'340993^^^&amp;2.16.840.1.113883.3.42.10002.1&amp;ISO'</rim:Value>
                   </rim:ValueList>
                </rim:Slot>
                <rim:Slot name="$XDSDocumentEntryStatus">
                   <rim:ValueList>
                      <rim:Value>'urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:StatusType:Approved'</rim:Value>
                   </rim:ValueList>
                </rim:Slot>
                <rim:Slot name="$XDSDocumentEntryClassCode">
                   <rim:ValueList>
                      <rim:Value>'51851-4'</rim:Value>
                   </rim:ValueList>
                </rim:Slot>
                <rim:Slot name="$XDSDocumentEntryClassCodeScheme">
                   <rim:ValueList>
                      <rim:Value>'LOINC'</rim:Value>
                   </rim:ValueList>
                </rim:Slot>
                <rim:Slot name="$XDSDocumentEntryCreationTimeFrom">
                   <rim:ValueList>
                      <rim:Value/>
                   </rim:ValueList>
                </rim:Slot>
                <rim:Slot name="$XDSDocumentEntryCreationTimeTo">
                   <rim:ValueList>
                      <rim:Value/>
                   </rim:ValueList>
                </rim:Slot>
             </rim:AdhocQuery>
          </query:AdhocQueryRequest>
       </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a Classpath issue.  My application had a dependency with a transitive dependency on Xerces, but the WebLogic wlfullclient.jar dependency was already has JAXP. I used the dependency "exclusions" configuration to remove the transitive Xerces dependency (groupId of "xerces", and "xml-apis" in other places in my code) and the issue went away.  Incidentally, before the code change, the test was working from the command line, just not from Eclipse.  Differences in loading the class may have led to the different results.